# Custom post type without editor or revisions - Notify on update?

Tags: custom-post-types, email

I've created a custom post type that makes use of custom fields over the default editor. I want to receive an email notification when an update to the post is made. The email does not have to show the diff (though it would be nice).

I've tried [Email Post Changes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-post-changes/) and it requires you to have "Revisions" enabled. I've tried enabling it and I am guessing, because I am not using the default editor, that it won't work without it.

Any thoughts on either getting the plugin working or figuring out how to have an email sent when a custom post type is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you publish a post, also custom post type, the hook get form status and post_type - `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` - is active and you can use this hook for send an mail. As an examaple for publish music: `add_action('publish_music', 'fb_my_function');` 
You can also send the revision inside the mail, the revision is only a other post type and can get from the database and add to the message of the mail.
Maybe you can see the possibilities on [my last plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inform-about-content/), send mails for comments and posts.

An simple example for custom post type "Archive"

```
public $post_type_1 = 'archiv';

add_action( 'publish_' . $this -> post_type_1, array( $this, 'fb_my_function') );

        public function fb_my_function( $post_id = FALSE ) {

            if ( $post_id ) {
                // get data from current post
                $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
                //var_dump($post_data);exit; <-- see this for all content or use the id for get the revisons

                // get mail from author
                $user_mail = get_userdata( $post_data -> post_author );

                // email addresses
                $to = 'test@example.com'
                // email subject
                $subject = get_option( 'blogname' ) . ': ' . $post_data -> post_title;
                // message content
                $message = $post_data -> post_content . ' ' . PHP_EOL .  
                    get_author_name( $post_data -> post_author ) . ' ' . PHP_EOL . . 
                    get_permalink( $post_id );
                // create header data
                $headers = 'From: ' . 
                    get_author_name( $post_data -> post_author ) . 
                    ' (' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . ')' . 
                    ' <' . $user_mail -> user_email . '>' . 
                    PHP_EOL;
                // send mail
                wp_mail( 
                    $to,
                    $subject, 
                    $message,
                    $headers
                );
            }

            return $post_id;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will take a closer look and update the question accordingly.