# Notify users whenever a new post is published based on their preference

Tags: functions

I have put together a custom registration form on my WordPress site and one of the items on the registration form is an ability to select an interest.

Essentially I have the following code from the registration form...

```
 update_usermeta( $user_id, 'interests', $_POST['interests'] );
```

I would need a code that does something like, if "interestes" matches "tag" of a new post, then send an email to the user.

Anything like that possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) How many tags are you dealing with? 2) Does the user have access to `/wp-admin/profile.php`? 3) How is the user entering the `interests`, as a comma separated value? 4) If `3` is true, this brings a bigger problem that is searching for partial matches. 5) Depending on `1` and `2`, a list of real tags could be presented in the Profile page for the user to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example on the [question 19259](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18839/custom-post-type-without-editor-or-revisions-notify-on-update/19259#19259).

The function was init on publish a post, change the hook to your post type or use on default `post` - Hook `publish_post`. Before you send check in the function your custom user meta field, like `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'interests', TRUE );` and ready to send the information about new post.

Maybe liek this solution, but untested!

```
    add_action( 'publish_post', 'fb_send_mail_about_new_post' );
    function fb_send_mail_about_new_post( $post_id = FALSE ) {

        // check user meta data, if interest
        $interests = FALSE;
        $interests = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'interests', TRUE );
        if ( ! $interests )
            return NULL;

        if ( $post_id ) {
            // get data from current post
            $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
            //var_dump($post_data);exit; <-- see this for all content or use the id for get the revisons

            // get mail from author
            $user_mail = get_userdata( $post_data -> post_author );

            // email addresses
            $to = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'email', TRUE );
            // email subject
            $subject = get_option( 'blogname' ) . ': ' . $post_data -> post_title;
            // message content
            $message = $post_data->post_content . ' ' . PHP_EOL . 
                get_author_name( $post_data->post_author ) . ' ' . PHP_EOL . 
                get_permalink( $post_id );
            // create header data
            $headers = 'From: ' . 
                get_author_name( $post_data -> post_author ) . 
                ' (' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . ')' . 
                ' <' . $user_mail -> user_email . '>' . 
                PHP_EOL;
            // send mail
            wp_mail( 
                $to,
                $subject, 
                $message,
                $headers
            );
        }

        return $post_id;
    }
```

A other alternative way is to use a plugin and leave many time, like this free plugin [Inform about Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inform-about-content/).
The plugin add two fields to the user profile for update of post and comment via mail. You can enhance with a custom plugin to the register site for new users to fill up this fields.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? You should be able to hook into [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) and then add the users email/remove it via a plugin like [subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) based on the value of that field.

If you want a more custom solution you could create your own plugin and do something like:

```
    class emailer {
  function send($post_ID)  {
    $friends = 'bob@example.org,susie@example.org';
    mail($friends,"sally's blog updated",'I just put something on my blog: http://blog.example.com');
    return $post_ID;
  }
}
$myEmailClass = new emailer();
add_action('publish_post', array($myEmailClass, 'send'));
```

Which is copy and pasted from the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

This would have to be modified with your if statement and a for-each but other than that should work. I would recommend just going with the first option though.

Comment: I briefly looked into "subscribe2" however, I wanted a notification based on user preferences. In other words, if they selected a particular tag that they're interested, then whenever a post with that tag appears, they will be notified. Not sure if "subscribe2" has anything like that.

Comment: @Richard, BandonRandon's code is part of the solution. The value of `$friends` has to be built based on the post tags and a search for matches inside all users meta.

Comment: use function `wp_mail()` as wp function, not `mail()`. It is easier to use for different installs and server-settings.